# Easy way to update GEOS, GDAL and PROJ on Windows via sf in R

Tags: r, gdal, r-sf, proj, geos

Is there a way to install from R more recent versions of these dependencies via sf?

How does sf install those in the first place, and how does it decide which version it installs. I browsed the source code, but couldn't find the answer.

https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2150

Comment: I cannot overstate how tough of a time I've had with this seemingly simple question, specifically that my sf is demanding GEOS 3.11 but will only connect to 3.10.2

So my solution has been to just use the geos package, which has (mostly) the same functions as sf but connects to the correct version of GEOS. Specifically I run 'geos_concave_hull()' because I get the error message 'st_concave_hull requires GEOS >= 3.11'

Comment: I found out the quickest way was to ask R core to update the deps. RTools43 now contains GEOS 3.11.12 https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/news.html https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2239#issuecomment-1765205764

I still wonder how to update it on old macOS